# Error: StringServices.insertString(...) is undefined

Tags: php, angularjs

I am New to angularjs, I am doing basic demo, in that I am inserting data into database using php and angularjs services and passing it to controller, the data is inserting into database but m getting error in console log. can anyone help me solve this error?

#### here is my app.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
//controller
app.controller("myController",['$scope','StringServices', function($scope,StringServices){
    $scope.User= {};
    $scope.insert = function(User){
        StringServices.insertString($scope.User, function(response){
            if(response.FLAG === "_SUCCESS"){
                console.log('Success');
            }
            else{
                console.log('Error');
            }
        }).error(function(error){
            console.error(error);
        }); 
    }
}])
//services

app.factory('StringServices', function($http){
    return {
        insertString: function(User){
            var data = {name: User.name};

            $http.post('http://localhost/anjali_services/server/insert.php',data)
            .success(function(response){
                return response;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

#### index.html

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Your Name</td>
        <td><input type= "text" ng-model="User.name"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="button" ng-click="insert(User)" value="Insert"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

#### insert.php

```
<?php 
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=anjali;port=3306","root","");
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
    $name = $data->name;
    $resp = array();
    $q = "INSERT INTO udata (name) VALUES (:name)";
    $query = $db->prepare($q);
    $execute = $query->execute(array(
        ":name" => $name
    ));
    if($execute == true){
        $resp['FLAG'] = "_SUCCESS";
        print json_encode($resp);
    }else{
        echo "ERROR";
    }

?>
```

#### i am getting this error

[See this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NBfw.png)

Comment: thanks for replying, I'm using StringService and insertString function and i have declre them correctly, but in console i'm getting error that StringService is not defined..

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your insertString function in StringServices takes only one argument that is User, however in your controller you are passing two arguments, i.e User and a function. thus no function insertString with two parameters.

You can have something like this:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
//controller
app.controller("myController",['$scope','StringServices', function($scope,StringServices){
    $scope.User= {};
    $scope.insert = function(User){
        StringServices.insertString($scope.User, function(response){
            if(response.FLAG === "_SUCCESS"){
                console.log('Success');
            }
            else{
                console.log('Error');
            }
        });
    }
}])
//services

app.factory('StringServices', function($http){
    return {
        insertString: function(User, callbackFn){
            var data = {name: User.name};

            $http.post('http://localhost/anjali_services/server/insert.php',data)
            .success(callbackFn);
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: so..could you please suggest me what should i do with this..??

Comment: @Sohlowmawn You are misinterpreting callback with second argument.

Comment: @ravishankar he is calling a function that takes one parameter, a callback function also needs to be passed as an argument. The function expects only one argument and he was passing two hence angular js won't find a function as such

Comment: Guys I'm sorry, but this is incorrect (as far as I see): This function receives one argument and that's it. Additional parameters that are passed to functions in JS are overlooked (unless you use the `arguments` object).

Comment: hello sir, i did same as u advice me... but now the console is printing "Success" message but again showing same error

Comment: @AranS let's not forget this is angular js not plain javascript

Comment: @Sohlowmawn, Angular is a framework that is built in JS (Typescript that compiles to JS).

Comment: @AtulGurnule i have removed the .error call in the controller

Comment: Thank you so much everyone now everything is working well.. i just removed error.function..from my controller...now it is working fine...

Comment: ^ Problem was that `error` wasn't defined, if you tried to run the code as-is. I don't see how this answer solved it (mine neither).

Answer (score 1):

I have to say I can't figure out the root of your problem right-away but I'd suggest you at least return `$http` promise from your service and handle result using `then/catch`. At least I find this more easy to read & understand what's going on.

Anyway, modifying your example in this way seems to work just nice. Against mock REST service anyway.

**HTML**

```
<body ng-controller="myController as vm">
  Your Name:
  <input type= "text" ng-model="User.name">
  <input type="button" ng-click="insert(User)" value="Insert">
</body>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myController', function($scope, StringServices) {
    $scope.User = {};

    $scope.insert = function(User) {
      StringServices.insertString(User)
        .then(function(response) {
          console.log('ok', response);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log('failed', error);
        });
    };
  })
  .factory('StringServices', function($http){
    return {
      insertString: function(User){
        return $http.post('https://httpbin.org/post', { name: User.name });
      }
    };
});
```

Related plunker here https://plnkr.co/edit/MVUSeg